# Ubuntu Screen shot File format

Tags: 14.04

Why the screenshots taken in UBUNTU systems cant be seen in windows systems ?
 ( I only tried in windows 7 )
The screenshot file format is .png

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Screenshots are saved with a default name consisting of the current Date and Time. That String contains ":" as a seperator for the timestamp, e.g. "12:02:45".

Unfortunately, due to the technical limitations of windows, this conflicts with the use of things like C:\ as a drive label. Therefore, any file name on Windows is not allowed to contain ":", as well as several other characters ("A filename cannot contain any of the following characters:
\ / : * ? " < > |" - Microsoft). Linux does not have any problems with this character though, which is why it is being used in the timestamp formatting.

So, if you rename your Screenshots to NOT include any of the characters mentioned above, you will be able to open/edit those on Windows too.

Unfortunately, this default behavior of the screenshot utility is hardcoded, so you either have to enter a valid filename when saving (Being descriptive with filenames never hurts) or rename them afterwards (this can easily be scripted) if you need to access them from Windows.